# 'android:indeterminateDrawable' creating incorrect image size

Tags: android

`android:indeterminateDrawable` is creating the incorrect image size.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/loading_process_dialog_progressBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminateDrawable="@anim/loading"/
```

This is layout description:
It will be show three circle bar in Nexus 5, but only two in Nexus one.

The image size in @anim/loading has 48px. What can be done to fix the size?

---

Comment: Not enough elements to provide an answer.

Comment: I face with same issue. I have 20 pictures in `animation-list`. Pictures have size 300x200px. When I set `indeterminateDrawable` to my animation-list it's scale incorrect. `wrap_content` does not work.